# PHP - Listar diretórios recursivamente e localizar arquivos

Tags: php

Bom dia a todos, gostaria de uma ajuda do pessoal, estou precisando entregar um projeto em **PHP** e me encontro empacado em uma determinada parte do mesmo, preciso listar recursivamente todos os diretórios que ficam dentro do **"D:\"**.

**Exemplo:**

```
D:\diretorio01\backup001\

D:\diretorio02\backup002\
              \backup003\

D:\diretorio03\backup004\
```

E depois de listar os diretórios, preciso localizar dentro deles todos os arquivos **.bak**.

É possível criar essa estrutura?

Desde já agradeço pelo apoio de todos envolvidos.

Comment: Pesquise sobre [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível, basta utilizar a função [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php):

```
foreach (glob('D:/**/*.bak') as $path) {
    echo $path, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Ela irá buscar todos os arquivos que possuem a extensão `.bak` em qualquer diretório dentro de `D:/`.

Comment: Fala Anderson, muito obrigado por responder, em partes deu certo sim, porem ele não localizou os .bak que estavam dentro do D:\ e nem localizou recursivamente dentro de diretórios a cima do D:\**\**\.

Sendo um pouco mais claro, não importa quantos diretórios eu tenho dentro do D:\ ou dentro de subdiretórios, eu preciso localizar todos .bak desde o D:\ até quantos níveis de diretório existente no D: .